# Is it possible to add custom metadata tags to music files?

Tags: audio, metadata, id3, id3-tag

I am working on a music player application and I'm not happy with the current standard for music tags. I would like to extend on the current ones. Is it possible to add custom metadata tags to audio files (MP3, OGG, FLAC, WAV)? Obviously only my application could read this metadata. Would adding custom metadata corrupt the files so they can't be played correctly by other players?

Comment: What are you trying to hide? There are a lot of frames that are available, perhaps http://id3.org/id3v2.3.0#User_defined_text_information_frame is a suitable one for your applications.

Comment: I'm not trying to hide any existing tags. I'd like to extend upon it to add my own.

Comment: "Obviously only my application could read this metadata." - by using ID3 tags correctly any application would be able to read them. If you're not hiding anything then use the user-defined text frames in ID3 to store your data. Please explain why this would not work for you.

Comment: Ogg and Flac both support tags with any name.

Comment: For anyone interested in finding out what is currently supported with OGG Vorbis https://xiph.org/vorbis/doc/v-comment.html#fieldnames

Answer (score 2):

Yes, most tagging formats support custom tags.

[ID3 allows TXXX.](http://id3.org/id3v2.3.0#User_defined_text_information_frame)

FLAC and Vorbis Comments both allow tags with any name (it's not really prescribed in the same way ID3 is).

You can do it with MP4 if you use XMP to contain the tags: [How can I embed metadata into a custom XMP field with exiftool?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29779144/how-can-i-embed-metadata-into-a-custom-xmp-field-with-exiftool)

Any other software that cannot work because a custom tag is set has bigger problems!