# How can I embed metadata into a custom XMP field with exiftool?

Tags: metadata, xmp, exiftool

Can someone please explain how to embed metadata into a custom metadata field in an MP4 file with exiftool? I've searched all the docs and it seems to be related to the config file that needs to be created. Here is what I'm working with. (I know this isnt even close, as its not doing XMP fields, but I havent found a single working example with XMP fields yet.

```
 %Image::ExifTool::UserDefined = (
'Image::ExifTool::Exif::Main' => {
    0xd001 => {
        Name => 'Show',
        Writable => 'string',
        WriteGroup => 'IFD0',    
},
);
1; #end
```

The command I'm trying to run is:

```
 exiftool -config exifToolConfig -show="Lightning" /reachengine/media/mezzanines/2015/02/13/13/CanyonFlight.mp4
```

Running this in a linux environment.

What is the properly way to set XMP metadata on custom metadata fields via ExifTool in linux on MP4 files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [sample exiftool config file](http://owl.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/config.html) contains a number of working examples of custom XMP tags.

Basically, it is done like this:

```
%Image::ExifTool::UserDefined = (
    'Image::ExifTool::XMP::Main' => {
        xxx => {
            SubDirectory => {
                TagTable => 'Image::ExifTool::UserDefined::xxx',
            },
        },
    },
);
%Image::ExifTool::UserDefined::xxx = (
    GROUPS => { 0 => 'XMP', 1 => 'XMP-xxx', 2 => 'Other' },
    NAMESPACE => { 'xxx' => 'http://ns.myname.com/xxx/1.0/' },
    WRITABLE => 'string',
    MyNewXMPTag => { },
);
```

Then the command is

```
exiftool -config myconfig -mynewxmptag="some value" myfile.mp4
```

Comment: I tried this on an mp4 file and keep getting this error:
     Error: Writing of MP4 files is not yet supported - Am I missing something here?

Comment: Does exifTool work with most MOV and MP4 files? Could there be a limitation thats causing it to just not be capable of adding metadata to my files? I added new fields to the Exif metadata via Adobe Premiere just fine.

Comment: Ok, got it working in OSX. But not Linux. Guessing I need to find a way to install the most updated version on Linux. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Any idea how to stop it from also generating a 2nd file named originalfilename.mov_original ?

Comment: Use the `-overwrite_original` option.